# How to count discrete variables in a dataset?

Tags: datatool

I am trying to count how many times each gender occurs in the table. The I would like to print those values inline with the rest of the text (I don't need any tables, but I am

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{datatool}

\newcommand*{\thePassGrade}{2.0}

\begin{filecontents*}{grade.csv}
name,givenname,matriculation,gender,grade
Maier,Hans,12345,m,1.0
Huber,Anna,23456,f,2.3
Weisbaeck,Werner,34567,m,5.0
Weisbaeck,Werner,34567,p,5.0
Weisbaeck,Werner,34567,q,5.0
Weisbaeck,Werner,34567,q,5.0
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb{grades}{grade.csv}

\begin{document}
\newcounter{m}
\newcounter{f}
\newcounter{p}
\newcounter{q}


\DTLforeach*{grades}{\name=name,\g=gender}{
\IfStrEq{\g}{m}{\stepcounter{m}}{
\IfStrEq{\g}{f}{\stepcounter{f}}{
\IfStrEq{\g}{p}{\stepcounter{p}}{
\IfStrEq{\g}{q}{\stepcounter{q}}}}
}}



There are \them and \thef and \thep and \theq

\end{document}
```

I am trying to get `There are 2 and 1 and 1 and 2`, instead I get an error.

Comment: Well, perhaps you should make your code *in principle* compilable by loading the `xstring` package and then mention that you get errors.

Comment: @marmot I found `IfStrEg` in the datatool documentation and I was unaware it came from another package but now I fixed it

Comment: And how about the error you ignore?

Comment: @Dambo Whereabouts in the documentation did you find it? There aren't any `xstring` examples in there as far as I remember?

Comment: @NicolaTalbot is `IfStrEq` the same as `IfStrEqual`? If yes, p.87

Comment: @Dambo Commands are case-sensitive and can't be abridged. Some of the examples use `\ifstrequal` which is provided by `etoolbox` (which is automatically loaded by `datatool`). That's not the same as `\IfStrEq` or `\IfStrEqual`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easier to use `\IfStrEqCase` instrad of a nested `\IfStrEq`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{datatool}

\newcommand*{\thePassGrade}{2.0}

\begin{filecontents*}{grade.csv}
name,givenname,matriculation,gender,grade
Maier,Hans,12345,m,1.0
Huber,Anna,23456,f,2.3
Weisbaeck,Werner,34567,m,5.0
Weisbaeck,Werner,34567,p,5.0
Weisbaeck,Werner,34567,q,5.0
Weisbaeck,Werner,34567,q,5.0
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb{grades}{grade.csv}

%% No need for this to be after \begin{document}
\newcounter{m}
\newcounter{f}
\newcounter{p}
\newcounter{q}


\begin{document}


\DTLforeach*{grades}{\name=name,\g=gender}{%
    \IfStrEqCase{\g}{%
        {m}{\stepcounter{m}}%
        {f}{\stepcounter{f}}%
        {p}{\stepcounter{p}}%
        {q}{\stepcounter{q}}%
    }%
}



There are \them\ and \thef\ and \thep\ and \theq.

\end{document}
```